# What else should I use to pass data between controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm using TempData to pass userID or other datas between my controllers but when user pushes ctrl+shift+r all my data gets cleaned. Is there a way to prevent this or what else should I use to pass data?

```
public ActionResult Index(Table_User user)
        {
            var user1 = repo.Find(x => x.UserMail== user.UserMail);
     
            if (user1 != null)
            {
                if (SecurityAlgorithms.CheckMD5Hash(user.UserPassword, user1.UserPassword))
                {
                    
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user1.UserName, false);
                    Session["user1"] = user.UserName;
                    var id = user.UserID;
                    User userinfo = new User()
                    {
                        userID= id
                    };
                  
                    TempData["UserData"] = userinfo;

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
                }
                
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Check your password!";
                    return View("Index", user);
                }
            }
```

```
public ActionResult Index()
       {
          
           User userdata= TempData["UserData"] as User;
           if (userdata== null)
           {
               ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "error";
               TempData["Message"] = "Error occurred: ";

               return View();
           }
           else
           {
           var values = db.Table_RentedBooks.Where(a => a.UserID== userdata.UserID).ToList();
           return View(values);

           }
       }
```

Comment: why don't you hold the value by public string variables ?

Comment: sorry I'm new to this so I don't know how to @Paramu

Comment: HI vives. I have seen you asking some related question about this topic recently. Why don't you look into this link and try to implement the Asp.net Identity. We don't have to reinvent the view, everything is there. https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/asp-net-core-identity-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

This is the method I usually use to pass data of one controller to another using `DependencyResolver`

**Steps of first controller**

1. Create public static object of `User` class inside `Home` controller *(In my case its home controller)* like this
2. Inside `Index` set the `userId` attribute

```
public class HomeController
{
    public static User _user;
    public HomeController()
    {
        _user = new User();
    }
    public ActionResult Index(Table_User user)
    {
        var user1 = repo.Find(x => x.UserMail== user.UserMail);
     
        if (user1 != null)
        {
            if (SecurityAlgorithms.CheckMD5Hash(user.UserPassword, user1.UserPassword))
            {
                    
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user1.UserName, false);
                Session["user1"] = user.UserName;
                var id = user.UserID;
                //Here set the id
                _user.userID= id;

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
            }
                
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Check your password!";
                return View("Index", user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Steps of second controller**

1. Inside controller class create an object of **first controller** and initialize it using `DependencyResolver`
2. Use this object to access the data

```
public class SecondController
{
    private readonly HomeController homeController = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<HomeController>();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {  
        User userdata= homeController._user;
        if (userdata== null)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "error";
            TempData["Message"] = "Error occurred: ";

            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            var values = db.Table_RentedBooks.Where(a => a.UserID== userdata.UserID).ToList();
            return View(values);
        }
    }
}
```